# Flutter Nested Navigator

Tags: flutter, nested, navigator

Hello I want to make a nested navigator like this
If not logged
/login
if Logged
/index
This will have a drawer menu and the body I want it to change based on the route
/index/dashboard
/index/clients … etc so basically only change the body once a drawer menu clicked .
From angular I were using ui-view package and it was easy to do.  and it seems its not possible to use nested navigators in flutter

the /index screen will only have a header and side menu drawer. as it is a web application

for now i am just redrawing all the screens everytime . and it is  like duplicated code.

any help is appreciated